# Getting strange Return Values from function when using VBA with excel

Tags: vba, function, return

I'm new to both Stack Overflow and VBA and hope i don't repeat a previously asked question.

The problem at hand is that i want a function in VBA that sends back a 1 if the condition is fulfilled and a zero if it isn't and i can't get this to work with the code below.

```
Sub Calculate(Total, X, Y, Z)  'doesn't work as expected

    valid_vlaue = CInt(Validity(Total, X, Y, Z))
    MsgBox valid_value


    If valid_value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Yes, Proceed"
    ElseIf valid_value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No, abort"
    End If


End Sub


Function Validity(Total, X, Y, Z) As Integer

    available_space = X * Y * Z
    Total = CInt(Total)
    available_space = CInt(available_space)

    'My_check = VarType(Total)
    'MsgBox My_check

    If Total <= available_space Then
        MsgBox "There is Room"
        Validity = 1
        Check = VarType(Validity)
        MsgBox Check
        Exit Function

    ElseIf Total > available_space Then
        MsgBox "There is not enough Room"
        Validity = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

This doesn't work as expected and nothing is ever returned and the false statement is always executed.

However when i wrote a testfunction as can be seen below everything works as expected.

```
Sub Test1()   'Works as expected

    Check = Test22(1)
    MsgBox Check
        If Check = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Proceed"
    ElseIf Check <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Abort"
    End If

End Sub



Function Test22(tmp) As Integer

    If tmp = 1 Then
        Test22 = 1
        Exit Function
    ElseIf tmp <> 1 Then
        Test22 = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

Could someone please explain to me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In addition to QHarr's remarks: It's a good idea to declare a variable for what you want to return from the function, then assign that to the function name at the end. Assign a default value to the variable at the beginning. The do NOT use `Exit Function` at all. In this particular case, I recommend using F8 to step through each line of code to see what is actually happening...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through this with a fine toothcomb but

**Notes:**

1. Put `Option Explicit` at the top - force declarations and check spelling and whether expected types are passed e.g.  `valid_value` or `valid_vlaue`
2. Use Long rather than Integer to avoid overflow.
3. Add the `ByVal` keyword to the signatures. Currently implicitly `ByRef`.
4. Explicitly state whether `Private` or `Public`.
5. Use meaningful variable names where possible and declare constants if constants. I haven't implemented this.
6. Avoid implicitly declaring everything as variants. Related to point 1.
7. Remove unnecessary type conversions. Pass initially as expected type. Unless I have misunderstood the purpose of your code, it is to check whether the sumproduct of a list of numbers is < or > a specified total.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Calculate 12, 6, 3, 3
End Sub

Public Sub Calculate(ByVal Total As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal Z As Long) 'doesn't work as expected
    Dim valid_value As Long

    valid_value = Validity(Total, X, Y, Z)
    MsgBox valid_value

    If valid_value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Yes, Proceed"
    ElseIf valid_value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No, abort"
    End If

End Sub

Public Function Validity(ByVal Total As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal Z As Long) As Long

    Dim available_space As Long
    available_space = X * Y * Z

    'My_check = VarType(Total)
    'MsgBox My_check

    Dim Check As Variant
    If Total <= available_space Then
        MsgBox "There is Room"
        Validity = 1
        Check = VarType(Validity)
        MsgBox Check
        Exit Function

    ElseIf Total > available_space Then
        MsgBox "There is not enough Room"
        Validity = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

**Test run:**

[image: Test run]

Answer (score 0):

Since Validity is to give you a go-no go result then you voukd make it as of boolean type (True-False)

Furthermore you can reduce your code (and errors!) to this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Calculate(Total As Variant, X As Variant, Y As Variant, Z As Variant)
    If Validity(Total, X, Y, Z)) Then ‘since Validity returns a boolean, you can simply check it
        MsgBox "Yes, Proceed"
    Else
        MsgBox "No, abort"
    End If
End Sub


Function Validity(Total As Variant, X As Variant, Y As Variant, Z As Variant) As Boolean
    Validity = CInt(Total) < CInt(X*Y*Z)
End Function
```

Finally, since Validity function consists of one line only, you could get rid of it:

```
Sub Calculate(Total As Variant, X As Variant, Y As Variant, Z As Variant)
    If CInt(Total) < CInt(X*Y*Z) Then ‘just make the check here!
        MsgBox "Yes, Proceed"
    Else
        MsgBox "No, abort"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help! Picked up a lot of good information!

The core of the problem turned out to be that i spelled "valid_value" wrong in the top. Despite trying to examine the code rigorously before posting the question here i somehow missed this.

I will make sure to make use of the tips i gotten here as well though.

Best Regards

Mange